# react-test-renderer incorrect peer dependency

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg

Doing a `yarn upgrade` today I am seeing the warning:

> warning "react-test-renderer@15.6.1" has incorrect peer dependency "react@^15.6.1"

I've tried upgrading react-test-renderer, but that didn't change anything.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Are you using `React v15.6.1` or higher?

Comment: I was going to say yes, but then I looked in my `'package.json` and saw `"react": "15.4.2",` so is that the issue?

Comment: exactly! `react-test-renderer` is expecting to work with `v15.6.1` or higher!

Comment: Boom! That was it. If you want to submit that in an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`react-test-renderer` is supposed to work with `react@^15.6.1` or higher, check your `package.json` to ensure you're React version is high enough.

Upgrading your react version to `react@^15.6.1` will remove this warning.